# How to make Vuex state update after axios call

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

I'm building a Nuxt app and I'm fetching some data from a node backend I've got running on my localhost.

I have a plugin getApps.js

```
export default ({ store }) => {
    store.dispatch('getApps')
}
```

That is calling a getApps action in my Vuex

```
actions: {
  getApps (context) {
    const {commit, state} = context
    commit('setLoading', true)

    let url = `apps?limit=${state.loadLimit}&page=${state.page}`

    if (state.query)
      url = `${url}/q=${state.query}`

    this.$axios.get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        const apps = res.data.apps
        console.log(apps)
        commit('addApps', apps)
        commit('setPage', state.page + 1)
        commit('setLoading', false)

      })
  }
  ...
```

The console.log here does indeed return the list of apps, however, after my addApps mutation

```
addApps (state, payload) {
  state.apps = payload
}
```

And this is the state definition

```
state: () => ({
  apps: [],
  query: '',
  loading: false,
  filters: [],
  loadLimit: 25,
  page: 1,
  showFilters: true,
  currentUser: null,
  showLoginModal: false,
  showCreateAppModal: false
})
```

The state doesn't get updated. As far as I could tell, this is due to the async nature of actions. I did also try to wrap the action around an async and prepend an await to the axios call, however, this did not work.

Why is this happening? How do I have to structure my code to make it work?

Comment: show your state definition

Comment: Sure, just added it right below the mutation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, you didn't aware with Promise. Your action call HTTP Request that is asynchronous, but you didn't `await` it.

And then, you should aware with Promise too in the Plugin section. The solution for your issue is very simple, you just need to `await`.

> plugins/getApps.js

```
export default async ({ store }) => {
    await store.dispatch('getApps')
}
```

> store/...

You can either make the function `async`, and `await` the axios, or you can return Promise from the action.

```
actions: {
  getApps (context) {
    ...
    return this.$axios.get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        const apps = res.data.apps

        commit('addApps', apps)
        ...
      })
  },
  ...
}
```

OR

```
actions: {
  async getApps (context) {
    ...
    await this.$axios.get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        const apps = res.data.apps

        commit('addApps', apps)
        ...
      })
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, it does work indeed! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @ilrock Cool! Glad if it helps. Up vote is more appreciated :D

Comment: Totally right, sorry! Just marked it as best answer. I also upvoted it now :)